# Determining the index of an item in a ManyToManyField and performing an operation from that

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been working with Django and I can't perform an operation based on the index of an item in a ManyToManyField.

I have the following code block

```
{% load mathfilters %}

{% for article in articles %}
    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.article_title }} - 
        {% for i in article.article_author.all %}
            {% if i == article.article_author.all.{{article.article_author.all.answer_set.count|sub:1}} %}
                {{i}},
            {% else %}
                {{i}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I want it to display a comma after the author's name indicating that there is another author, but only if that author is not the last author listed in the ManyToManyField. I cannot figure out how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [forloop variants](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof)

In this case:

```
        {% for i in article.article_author.all %}
            {% if forloop.last %}
                //it's a  good idea to check for last so one item lists don't get commas
                {{i}}
            {% else %}
                {{i}},
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```